# Airflow API Version is binded with Airflow Version

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

Is there any reason for the last stable API be present only in Airflow > 2.4.0. At this moment, the last airflow version in Google Cloud Composer is 2.3.4, and I the API version does not allow dag_run_id field in body request for clearInstances endpoint. Can I update API separtedly or API Version is binded with Airflow versions?

The same occurs running on local machine.

Thank You!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm also facing a similar situation.

Comment: Unfortunately no.